# How to show emoji in gitk

Tags: emoji, gitk

I'm beginner for git-cz.It makes commit easier to read with emoji.But the emoji was replaced in gitk. Just like follow picture. How to make emoji work??

[image: emoji in gitk]

It's work fine for git log.
[image: emoji in git log]